# How to close the parent window from within the iframe without making any changes in the parent?

Tags: javascript, iframe

the code of the parent window is not accessible. It contains an iframe in which the content of the new page is loaded. Now a logout button should be added in the new page so that when it is clicked the tab should be closed.
I tried many solutions nothing seems to work.

Comment: If you don't have the access permissions to the parent window and you can't change the code of the parent window, you can't do it: it would be a security risk. Nothing *should* work.

Comment: In parent there is a function to close window but when that is invoked i am getting "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it" error.. :(